# Why countdown value is decreasing more fast less than 1 second ,as I set timeout for every second and on template display more fast?

Tags: angular, raspberry-pi

## Why is the countdown value decreasing faster than 1 second,as I settimeout for every second and on template display more fast?

I want the countdown value to decrease every second and when it reaches 0 then move to the home directory.
This is my code of the component.

```
this.subscription2 = timer(0,1000).pipe(
        switchMap(()=>this.nextPressed())
      ).subscribe(
        (result:any)=>{
          console.log("In bottle subscription2 ",result)
          if(result["next"]=="yes" && this.phoneWin == true){
              this.phoneWin=false;
              this.isCountingStart =false;
              this.countdown = 30;
              this.router.navigateByUrl('phone'); 
                   }
          else if(result["next"]=="no" && this.phoneWin == true){
              console.log("In Bottle else part");
              if(!this.isCountingStart){
                this.isCountingStart =true;
                this.startCountdown();
              }
              if(this.countdown == 0){
                this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
              }
   
              }
             
              
          }
      
      );
    }

crushBottle(){
    this.stopCounter();
    this.isCrushing = true;
    this.phoneWin =true;
    this.turnOnRelay();
    console.log("In crushbottle fun",this.counter);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCrushing = false;
        this.dataService.addBottles();
        this.counter += 1;
        console.log("Bottle count",this.counter);
        this.dataService.addBottles();
        this.turnOffRelay() ; 
        this.timedStartCounter();
        
      }, 5000);     
     
  }


  //  For countdown function
  startCountdown(){
    this.isCountingStart = true;
    this.phoneWin =true;
    console.log("In startCountdown methos",this.counter);
    const countdownFunction =() =>{
      this.countdown -= 1;
      console.log("After decreasing counter by 1",this.countdown);

      if (this.countdown > 0) {
        console.log("startCountdown vfunction called");
        setTimeout(countdownFunction, 1000); 
    } else {
      this.isCountingStart =false;
      // this.countdown =30;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    }
    }
      setTimeout(countdownFunction,1000);       
     
  }


  timedStartCounter(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.restartCountdown();
  }, 5000);
  }

  restartCountdown(){
    this.countdown =30;
    this.isCountingStart = true;
    this.startCountdown();
  }
  stopCounter(){
    this.isCountingStart =false;

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // this.phoneWin =false;
    this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
    this.subscription2.unsubscribe();
  }
```

On Template countdown value should be updated every second by decreasing by 1 but here it is more frequently that seconds

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `setInterval` more appropriate for this scenario? When you use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` always ensure that the previously set ones are cleared using `clearInterval`!

```
export class component {

    myInterval = null;
    
    startCountdown(){
        if(this.myInterval) {
            clearInterval(this.myInterval);
        }
        this.isCountingStart = true;
        this.phoneWin =true;
        console.log("In startCountdown methos",this.counter);
        const countdownFunction = () =>{
          this.countdown -= 1;
          console.log("After decreasing counter by 1",this.countdown);
    
          if (this.countdown <= 0) {
              this.isCountingStart =false;
              // this.countdown =30;
              if(this.myInterval) {
                  clearInterval(this.myInterval);
              }
              this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
          }
        }
        this.myInterval = setInterval(countdownFunction,1000);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive,try this

```js
function doSomeThing() {
    // your code to do any thing you want
}

function showTime(time) {
    // show the time function in angular
}

function countdown(seconds, showTime, doSomeThing) {
    let time = seconds
    function tick() {
        showTime(time)
        time--
        if (time > 0)
        {
            let set = setTimeout(tick, 1000)
        }
        if (time == 0)
        {
            doSomeThing()
        }
}
    tick()
}
countdown(10, showTime, doSomeThing)
```